# App does not post to user's timeline

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have developed an app using Facebook Graph API and Open Graph. I want my app to display custom data, when the user performs an action on my website. I read about open graph and added a open graph tags, etc. I have used the following code

```
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/myappnamespace:mycustomaction?method=post".
    "&mycustomobject=mywebpage".
    "&access_token=".$_SESSION['access_token'];
```

Right now, whenever a user uses this app, it appears in his activity. But, it is not shared on his timeline. What permissions do i need to ask the user to be able to post to his own timeline? Currently, I am asking for publish_actions and publish_stream

What am I missing? I followed the exact steps in the tutorial, but am not able to post to the timeline using opengraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to add any permissions except `publish_actions` and `publish_stream`. But you should add a new tag like `fb:explicitly_shared`. Set this as `BOOL` value. If you set true, it will show in the user's timeline, else it will not.