# Sharing to Facebook Wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook sdk and need to share details to facebook timeline. I am using the following api call.

```
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/feed"
                             parameters:dictionary
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
          [VBUtility showAlertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Deal details posted successfully"];
     }
 }];
```

The story is published on facebook, not at user's timeline but user's newsfeed (The document tells this method does - posts and links published by this person or others on their profile.). I have also tried with /home method call. While I tried with the built in facebook share,

```
SLComposeViewController *fbPost = [SLComposeViewController
                                   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

it is perfectly published to user's timeline as well as in news feed. I have configured the app in the developer.facebook.com. Do I need to mention any permissions here. Does any one can help me finding the mistake?
Permission Request,

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"user_birthday",@"publish_stream",@"user_about_me",@"email",@"basic_info",nil];
```

The parameters passed are,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   app_id, @"app_id",
                                                   name,@"name",
                                                   caption, @"caption",
                                                   description,@"description",
                                                   link, @"link",
                                                   picture, @"picture",
                                                   @"1",@"fb:explicitly_shared",
                                                   nil];
```

Comment: So, you want to share in the user's timeline?.

Comment: Yes, the things that are shared using SLComposeViewController is both appearing on timeline as well as news feed. I need the same functionality

Comment: have you tried my answer?. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15217580/2629258 otherwise, tell me we can try any other solution.

Comment: updated question with my parameter list. It doesn't worked.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy I have updated the post with permission request and parameters that are passed to the service

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @sathiamoorthy No, the content is posted to News Feed. Not visible to TimeLine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:dictionary
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
          [VBUtility showAlertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Deal details posted successfully"];
     }
 }];
```

I changed little bit from your code. Change your path as `@"me/feed"`. I hope, this may help you.

Comment: You added comment like "You had tried this?". Is it working now?

Comment: Yes. but it was before adding the the tag "fb:explicitly_shared" .Thanks a lot

Comment: @GovindPN by using "me/feed" it is working? or have done anything else?